# How to create a directory in external storage on Android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have updated `compileSdkVersion 29` and `targetSdkVersion 29`

Now `mkdir()` is not working. I am aware of `Storage Access Framework (SAF)` and `Scoped Storage`. My app download videos and is stored in `external storage` directory. That's because I don't want to lose all downloaded videos when I uninstall the app.

So, how can I create an `external storage` directory regardless of `sdk` version?

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to select the primary partion or the Downloads directory or the micro SD card.

Comment: Thanks. It's working with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE